# iOS NSURLConnection - Error description from response

Tags: php, ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

With NSURLConnection, I'm able to get the error code returned by my php web service, but is there a way to get the error description instead? To get the error code I'm using the following code:

```
int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSHTTPURLResponse` doesn't contain the error code description as you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your service returns the error description in the response body, you can accumulate it into an `NSMutableData` using the `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method, just as you would do with a normal response.

Answer (score 0):

Hope that helps:

```
NSString *error = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]];
```